# Wordpress plugin template override - portfolio

Tags: php, templates, wordpress, portfolio

I am using this Worpress plugin: http://bestwebsoft.com/plugin/portfolio-plugin/

I already changed the portfolio itself by including the requests into my own template, but if i click onto one of the items, it directs me to the /portfolio/ permasite, which is then displaying the requested portfolio item in detail.

Now here is my question: I do know where to find the template for this single display (portfolio-post.php) but I'd like to change it myself, without risking to lose the template when I update the plugin. So editing *within* the portfolio plugin folder is not an option for me.

Is there any method to change this template by placing a "portfolio-post.php" whatever in my own theme folder?

Comment: You should ask that the author of that plugin *or* look into the code how it works on your own.

Comment: In the plugin's FAQ: *"I updated the plugin, the template changed, but I would like to revert it back as it was before? What should I do?"*

Comment: alright I thought that maybe wordpress has some kind of 'override rule' that themes in your own theme folder will always override the template of the plugin. Good to know thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create the portfolio-post.php file in your template folder and edit it there, you don't have the risk that an update will overwrite it.

As long as you position the file inside the same folder basis as in the plugin you should be fine

e.g. /your-theme-folder/portfolio-post.php

Comment: the original theme file is in:
wp-content/plugins/portfolio/template/portfolio-post.php

I have pasted mine in:
wp-content/themes/dw2/portfolio/template/portfolio-post.php

nothing changed :/

Comment: The author says at http://wordpress.org/plugins/portfolio/installation/ > Please check if you have the template files 'portfolio.php' and 'portfolio-post.php' in your templates directory. If you can't find these files, then just copy them from the directory '/wp-content/plugins/portfolio/template/' to your templates directory. So it should work...

Comment: hah.. it worked. but the files get directly into 'wp-content/themes/theme-name/', not the subfolder portfolio etc.

Comment: aha :) nice that it works ;)